# Cannot reinstall iMessage Extension after explicitly uninstalling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imessage, imessage-extension

I have an iMessage extension included in my main app. Added to the project like so:

[image]

And then chose my app Xcode Project from the "Embed in Application" dropdown (I already did this step, the screenshot was taken afterwards to help explain my question):
[image]

I pushed a new build to the iTunes Connect and TestFlight. Another tester and myself than explicitly deleted the iMessage extension (NOT the main app) like so:

[image]

Now the tester and myself cannot get the embedded iMessage Extension to reinstall. We have explicitly deleted the main app and reinstalled and that did not reinstall the embedded iMessage extension.

I even incremented the build number (not the version number) and pushed another build to TestFlight to try and trigger and fresh reinstall.

I am going to increment the version number of my app now (even though there are no changes) to see if that will get the iMessage Extension to reinstall.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It looks the an iPhone will remember an explicit decision to uninstall an iMessage Extension and though a new install of the main app with an embedded iMessage Extension will install the extension again it is now off by default and has to be explicitly reenabled:

[image]